# Converting a kafka value binary payload to string on Azure Databricks

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm reading a Kafka json file from Azure ADLS Gen2 storage account on Azure Databricks. I dont seem to be able to convert the value binary payload to string so that I can perform the from_json conversion. I've tried various flavours of the cast and in all cases the original binary value is shown in my final transformation.

I've tried ...
df.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)")

as well as ...
df.select(col("value").cast("string"))

I know i'm doing something stupid, cause this is a trivial transformation, but I cant work out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using Azure Databricks Runtime 11.3 LTS ML

Sample data that i'm using is a Databricks Academy dataset
[image]

I'm expecting the above code to transform this into human readable string format but the final transformation for the 'value' is identical to the original binary.

Comment: What do you mean by "Kafka json file"? Kafka has topics, which would come from Azure EventHubs, for example, not ADLS

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is correct to get it to a string, but perhaps the data is simply not actually a string? Perhaps your data is **actually** an encoded (base64, maybe) / encrypted string, or a binary payload such as Avro, Protobuf, etc which are not human readable.

Without knowing how it was produced, you cannot know how to deserialize it; and if you are reading a `.json` file, as you say, then Spark doesn't care about file extensions...

Answer (score 0):

Exactly 1 year later I ran into the same issue.
I found a solution based on [this link](https://www.confluent.io/blog/consume-avro-data-from-kafka-topics-and-secured-schema-registry-with-databricks-confluent-cloud-on-azure/#step-7).

Simply cast your column to `StringType()`. This does encoding the values and converts them from byte to utf-8 strings. From there you should be able to convert the values to a dict or other desired type.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType


df = (spark
  .readStream
  ...
  .load()
  .withColumn('value', fn.col("value").cast(StringType()))
  )

display(df)
```